# How can I convert a word EQ field to a OMath object?

Tags: vba, ms-word

See, I have many EQ fields in a `.docx` file such as `eq \f(1,2)` which looks like this: [image].

And now I want to convert it to a `OMath` object, what should I do?

I've tried copy and paste it with `.Copy` and `.PasteAndFormat` methods but it doesn't work.

Comment: EQ fields are the oldest form of equation editor, having appeared in Word 1.0. You used to be able to convert to MathType back when that was still included in Word. You'll probably have to write a routine that deconstructs the equation from the field, then rebuilds it as an oMath object. Here's an article with lots of background information that may help you figure out a method: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK350572/

Comment: @JohnKorchok Every much thanks! I've also tried using MathType 6.9 to convert the EQ fields, but it seems that it can't convert it to a MathType Equation, and converting it to a text version such as MathML 2 works not evey well, cause some information of equations (such as operators "+-") is lost.

Comment: @JohnKorchok I've solved this problem by, as you say, writing codes myself to deconstruct the EQ field and build them in OMath object with RegEx. It's not as difficult as I thought it would be. Anyway, thanks.